# Checkbox visual force page throwing collection limit errors, not entering method it's supposed to

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following VisualForce page which essentially mimics the work of this checkbox class for the developerforce wiki: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Checkbox_in_DataTable.

The problem is that when I run the program, it seems that the getAssets method (shown as !assets in visualforce page) is running a few times one after the other and thus eventually gives me a collection limit error.

However, I've put in debug statements everywhere on the controller class and funnily enough when I look at my debug logs, it seems that it never enters the getAssets method but somehow it exits the method.

If you would like me to attach the debug logs, I will be happy to oblige. I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing so much more differently than what's happening in the wiki page above and I'm not sure why it's throwing the error it is.

```
    <apex:page controller="Checkbox_Class_V2" Tabstyle="Asset" readOnly="false">
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock Title="Quote Calculator">
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:600px; height:500px">  
                <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Assets - Excludes all Retired and Returned Assets">
                    <apex:dataTable value="{!assets}" var="a" columnswidth="50px,50px" cellpadding="4" border="1">
                        <!--makes a call to the getAssets() method in the Checkbox_Class Controller-->
                           <apex:column >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">
                                        <apex:inputCheckbox >
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" onsubmit="checkAll(this,'checkedone')"/>
                                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                    </apex:facet>
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.selected}" id="checkedone"></apex:inputCheckbox>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column headervalue="Asset Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}" />
                    </apex:dataTable>                      
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </div>
                <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Actions" >
                 <apex:commandButton action="{!GetSelected}" value="Submit"/>
                 <!--   <apex:outputText value="{!SelectedAssets}"/>-->  
                </apex:pageBlockSection>                
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
<script>
function checkAll(cb)
{
var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
{
    if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
}


}   
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Here is my controller page shown below with only the relevant methods that I use in the visualforce page:

```
    public List<assetswrapper> getAssets() 
    {
system.debug('entered getAssets');

        List<Pricebook2> Pbook2Id = [   
                                        SELECT Name,ID                                   
                                        FROM Pricebook2 
                                        WHERE Name='Support Renewal' AND IsActive=true
                                    ];


        List <PricebookEntry> supportRenewal = [
                                        SELECT ID, ProductCode, UnitPrice  
                                        FROM PricebookEntry 
                                        WHERE ProductCode Like 'MAR%'
                                              AND 
                                              Pricebook2Id in: Pbook2Id];
        for(PricebookEntry pbEntryMar : supportRenewal)     


        for(Asset a : [
                                        SELECT SerialNumber, Name                           
                                        FROM Asset
                                        WHERE (Retired__c != true AND Returned__c != true)
                                        AND Product_Code__c IN: wrapMarProductCodes //AND Entitlement__c=:entId //ignore all Retired and Returned Assets.
                                        LIMIT 100] ){

            assetsList.add(new assetswrapper(a));} //as each asset is processed, we create a new assetswrapper object and add it to the assetslist
system.debug('Exited getassets');
        return assetsList; // return the assetsList list when called. // 

    } //END OF PUBLIC LIST<ASSETSWRAPPER> GETASSETS()

    public PageReference getSelected()
    {
system.debug('entered getSelected');

        utility.selectedAssets.clear(); 
        //utility.populateEndDates();
        for(assetswrapper accwrapper : assetsList)
        {
            if(accwrapper.selected == true)
            {
                System.debug('TESTING');
                utility.selectedAssets.add(accwrapper.acc);
            }    
        }
system.debug('finish getSelected');

        if(utility.selectedAssets.size()>0 && utility.endDate!=null)        
            return QTC.QuoteCalculatorVThree(utility);
        else 
            return null;         
    } //END OF PUBLIC PAGEREFERENCE GETSELECTED()
```

Comment: why are you using value="{!getassets}" in your data table? It should be {!assets}!!! Do you have a property that has a name getassets (eg public list<string> getassets{get;set;}? you cannot have a method as a getter and use in your datatable as {getmethodname}

Comment: that was just me trying to test different ways to get it to work. My mistake. The above code has been fixed to show just !assets. However, the error still persists.

Comment: What do you mean the error persists, does the code enter the method now and are you able to debug your code to see why the collection limit is exceeding?

Comment: it enters the method now and I have been debugging line by line to see where it fails. It seems that the getAssets() method is getting rendered multiple times i.e. on the visual force page, every time I select an asset, the getAssets() method runs from the beginning. This is the reason why i'm going over the collection limit.

Comment: What is the text of the error which you're getting? Something similar to _Collection size 1,001 exceeds maximum size of 1,000_? How many elements do you anticipate will be in your return `List<AssetsWrapper>`?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some brackets, but it looks like you are querying inside a for loop:

```
for(PricebookEntry pbEntryMar : supportRenewal)     

    for(Asset a : [
                                    SELECT SerialNumber, Name                           
                                    FROM Asset
                                    WHERE (Retired__c != true AND Returned__c != true)
                                    AND Product_Code__c IN: wrapMarProductCodes //AND Entitlement__c=:entId //ignore all Retired and Returned Assets.
                                    LIMIT 100] ){
```

It doesn't even seem like you use the PBEs at all...So based on the code you have posted you can remove most of the getter method entirely:

```
public List<assetswrapper> getAssets() 
{
    for(Asset a : [
                                    SELECT SerialNumber, Name                           
                                    FROM Asset
                                    WHERE (Retired__c != true AND Returned__c != true)
                                    AND Product_Code__c IN: wrapMarProductCodes
                                    LIMIT 100] )
    {
            assetsList.add(new assetswrapper(a));
    }
    return assetsList;

}
```

I would also call `assetsList.clear()` at the beginning, but it's hard to tell with incomplete code.